# pygame не закрывается окно

Tags: python, разработка-игр, события, pygame

Создаю окно. Оно запускается, но закрываться не хочет. Зависает намертво

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    size = [240,180]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("window")

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас идет цикл и когда он заканчивается ничего не происходит. Для того чтобы у вас закрывалась программа то используйте библиотеку  `sys` функцию `sys.exit()` или без библиотеки `exit()` или `quit()`

```
import pygame
import sys


def main():
    pygame.init()
    size = [240, 180]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("window")
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: все так же сделал все равно не хочет закрываться у меня питон 3.6

Answer (score 2):

Все нашел решение. Какие-то особенности виндовс)

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    size = [240,180]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("window")

    while True:
        event = pygame.event.wait()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
    pygame.quit ()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```